# Using login details from file_get_contents() to connect to MS-SQL server causes error

Tags: php, sql-server, file-get-contents

The following is the piece of code I am using to connect to a MS-SQL 2008 server

```
<?php
     $server = 'serverName';
     $user = file_get_contents('user.txt');
     $pwd = file_get_contents('pwd.txt');

     //Testing whether user and pwd are okay
     echo 'User: '.$user;
     echo 'Pwd: '.$pwd

     //Connecting to MS-SQL server
     $conn = mssql_connect($server, $user, $pwd);
     if(!$conn)
     {
         echo 'Problem connecting to server';
         die(print_r(mssql_get_last_message(), true));
     }
?>
```

This is giving me a 'The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication'.

But when I modify the above code to

```
$user = 'userName';
$pwd = 'password';
```

it successfully connects to the server!

I have printed out the contents of the username and password when I use `file_get_contents()` and it looks fine. I am unable to figure out why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

System details:
PHP version: 5.3.3
CentOS 6.4 x64
Apache version: 2.2.15

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to inspect data. Plain `echo` will hide lots of details.

Comment: I'm wondering why even using `.txt` files to login to a DB, kind of defeats the purpose. Better hide those files really well also.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Thanks for the var_dump() tip. Made me realize that there was white space being added

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I am just using a VM to do some testing. Will not be using txt files once I shift to a non-testing environment. BTW, what method would you suggest for storing login details?

Comment: Store it all inside a DB / different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There maybe some whitespace getting added whilst you load from the text file.. Try trimming

```
$user = trim(file_get_contents('user.txt'));
$pwd = trim(file_get_contents('pwd.txt'));
```

Comment: Being picky, my password could actually start or end with spaces :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`file_get_contents()` function](http://php.net/file_get_contents) returns:

> the read data or `FALSE` on failure

If either `$user` or `$pwd` are `FALSE` then it's clear why it's failing. Otherwise, the files do not contain the correct credentials—PHP has no way to know where a given string variable comes from. Most likely, you have leading or trailing non-printable characters (such as spaces or line feeds). To inspect the variables:

```
var_dump($user, $pwd);
```

Make sure you check the character count.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The white space was the issue, which I solved by using trim();